# Can't find laser_scan_matcher parameters

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, laser-scan-matcher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Kinetic

Ubuntu 16.04

Goal

I'm trying to launch a Laser_Scan_Matcher node (from scan_tools package) that takes in `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2` messages and outputs `geometry_msgs/PoseStamped`.

The package is correctly installed. demo.launch works.

In the node.cpp file I see

```
if(use_cloud_input=True)
```

but can't find

```
set.Param("use_cloud_input", True/False)
```

anywhere in any file in any folder inside the laser_scan_matcher package!
How do I launch this node specifying cloud input?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288176/can%27t-find-laser_scan_matcher-parameters/) by [anonymous32749](https://answers.ros.org/users/32749/anonymous32749/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2018-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The true / false value for the use_cloud_input_ param is initialized on [line 148](https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/scan_tools/blob/indigo/laser_scan_matcher/src/laser_scan_matcher.cpp#L148) in laser_scan_matcher.cpp (Indigo branch) with the following code:

```
if (!nh_private_.getParam ("use_cloud_input", use_cloud_input_))
use_cloud_input_= false;
```

So in your launch file you just need to specify the parameter to true. Also, by default laser_scan_matcher looks for the pointcloud on the "cloud" topic (verify this), so you'll also want to remap to whatever your pointcloud topic is. An example launch file might look something like this:

```
<launch>
<node pkg="laser_scan_matcher" type="laser_scan_matcher_node" name="matcher_node">
<remap from="cloud" to="pointcloud_topic" />
<param name="use_cloud_input" value="true"/>
</node>
</launch>
```

Hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) with karma: 929 on 2018-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous32749](https://answers.ros.org/users/32749/anonymous32749/) on 2018-04-12**:
Thank you!